# Swift 3 - AES Encryption Heimdall - Zero Padding

Tags: swift, encryption, key, aes, rsa

i am using Heimdall

```
https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall
```

for generating my 1024 bit RSA keys and encrypting messages:

```
let heimdall = Heimdall(publicTag: publicTag, publicKeyData: data)
```

When i utf8-encode and base64-encode i pass it to the encrypt method:

```
let utf8Encoded = self.mystring.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64Encoded = utf8Encoded.base64EncodedData()
let encrypted = heimdall.encrypt(base64Encoded)
print("encrypted \(encrypted!)") // -> 160 bytes !! why not 128
```

The encrypted part should 128 bytes and not 160.

Can anybody help me to get there?

How can i keep generating 1024 bit rsa keys and encrypting messages with those keys to end up with 128 byte arrays?

Thanks and Greetings !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Heimdall docs: [Note on encryption/decryption](https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall#note-on-encryptiondecryption):
*The payload is built, containing the encrypted key, followed by the encrypted message.*
Then this is Base64 encoded increasing the length by 1/3.

Thus the output is (the aes key + the encrypted data length + padding) Base64 encoded.

Comment: yea.. in the method "open func encrypt(_ data: Data) -> Data?" i commented "result.append(encrypted)" and now i have 128 bytes...but my endpoint still tells me that is an invalid endpoint..any suggestions?

Comment: or wait.. is there any possiblity to remove the padding?

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove the padding, Heimdall should do that for you. How are you decryprion it, alsp with Heimdall? Ypu need to add a [mcve] to the question, thaat would include sample data, data in hex of course.

Comment: okey sure thanks for the asnwer:) i will update soon. Can you tell me how many bytes each part of the payload takes?

Comment: You will have to read the docs/code to find out what the defaults are or how to set them yourself (the beast way). It says the key can be any of the three AES key sizes. Also there is the issue of padding, a possible IV, etc. One of the biggest problem with open source software is the really poor documentation.